# Integrating Cosecant by Multiplying it by $\csc(x)+\cot(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

From what I’ve seen you integrate cosecant by multiplying it by $\csc(x)+\cot(x)$:

How do you know to multiply it by this?

Comment: "How do you know to.." depends on what you know, of course.  Possibly you know the [corresponding integration trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_only_secant) for integrating $\sec x$, in which case the formula for $\csc x$ is naturally justified by change of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin{x}}dx=\int\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin^2x}dx=\int\frac{\sin{x}}{1-\cos^2x}dx=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{1+\cos{x}}+\frac{1}{1-\cos{x}}\right)d(\cos{x})=$$
$$=-\ln\frac{1+\cos{x}}{1-\cos{x}}+C=\ln\frac{1-\cos{x}}{1+\cos{x}}+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}$$